# Android studio - package com.google.android.gms.authn does not exist

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Using android-studio 1.5 and  getting error when run in device

Error:(26, 36) error: `package com.google.android.gms.authn does not exist`

Added in gradle setting

```
dependencies {    
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
```

}. Help to fix

Comment: Does the device that you are using [run Android 2.3 or higher and include Google Play Store](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)?

Comment: yes. version 5.0.1